# Using volttron-cfg to configure volttron central (VC)

Tags: volttron

While using volttron-cfg, I was asked some questions:

1. **Include volttron central platform agent on volttron central? [Y]** Is VC platform agent is the backend agent and VC is the frontend?
2. What is port 22916 (vip port)? The content returned from
   "localhost:22916" is not readable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VOLTTRON central agent(VC) connects to the individual VOLTTRON instances through the VOLTTRON central platform agent(VCP).

Both the VC and VCP agents are not considered platform agents because they aren't started up when you start VOLTTRON by default.

When using the volttron-cfg command the question is asking you do you want to have a VCP as well as a VC installed on whatever instance you are setting up.

The port 22916 is the VIP ([VOLTTRON Interconnect Protocol](http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/core_services/messagebus/VIP/VIP-Overview.html?highlight=VIP)) port that allows all of the VOLTTRON agents to connect with the VOLTTRON router.  If you have a VOLTTRON instance running (and left as the default port), you can telnet to it and see that it is indeed running.  You will not be able to browse to it however as it is not serving http requests from that port.

Comment: Question 1 Include volttron central platform agent on volttron central? [Y] What if I say No?

Comment: If you say no then there won't be a VCP agent installed on the instance you are configuring.

Comment: Does that mean I would not able to access VC web fronend?

Comment: VC and VCP are distinct.  You can use VC without any VCP agents if you need to.